# Twitter query string

Tags: twitter

When i have in query string %20 twitter just cut off the url.

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=49.248.29.163/planPage?Title=Religare%20Invesco%20AGILE%20Fund&classification=equity&text=Check%20this%20via%20@ReligareInvesco

Does anybody know the solution?

Link to twitter thread:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-url-with-querystring-having-spaces/38295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation for intents](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent) Your *entire* `url` needs to be URL Encoded.

That means `/` becomes `%3F` and so on.

In addition, the documentation says that the URL must be *fully qualified*. That is, it must start with `https://` or similar.

Finally, the spaces must be *double encoded*. That means the `%` symbol in `%20` needs to become `%25`.

The `url` parameter should be:

`https%3A%2F%2F49.248.29.163%2FplanPage%3FTitle%3DReligare%2520Invesco%2520AGILE%2520Fund%26classification%3Dequity`

You can test this at https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2F49.248.29.163%2FplanPage%3FTitle%3DReligare%2520Invesco%2520AGILE%2520Fund%26classification%3Dequity&text=Check%20this%20via%20@ReligareInvesco

Comment: Great I miss that out, thnx.